# How to redirect all but one request using .htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website build with React that uses Wordpress solely as a CMS. Routes are handled on the frontend side with `react-router` but because of that, I cannot access my WordPress admin page since all the routes are redirected to `index.html`.

I would like to redirect all routes to `index.html` except this one, which links to my admin panel: `www.mysite.com/wordpress/wp-login.php`

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I tried this, but it didn't help:

```
...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: do you have `.htaccess` file in `www.mysite.com/wordpress/` path?

Comment: Yes, I have one there, but I didn't notice it before. The one I'm showing in the question above is the one I have in my root folder. What should I do with the one from `wordpress` folder? Should I pass `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress` there?

Answer (score 1):

Your wordpress folder should have this htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^/wordpress/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with this code in your .htaccess (explanations in code):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # this line allows direct login to www.mysite.com/wordpress/wp-login.php
    RewriteRule ^wordpress/wp-login\.php$ - [L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # everything else goes to www.mysite.com/index.html
    RewriteRule . index.html [L,NC]
    </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```